# Cucumber Feature - data population handling Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cucumber

I have a ActiveRecord in Rails that has a
serialize :file_names, Array
field

In my cucumber details.feature I have something like the following:

```
Given the following dist_details exist
     | effective_date | company_id | file_names           | sent_at             |
     |     2012-03-01 |          1 | test1.pdf,test2.pdf  | 2012-04-01 13:00:00 |
     |     2012-04-01 |          2 | test3.pdf,test4.pdf  | 2012-04-01 14:00:00 |
```

when I run my cucumber test I get the following error:

```
Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a String
(ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch)
      ./features/step_definitions/pickle_steps.rb:15:in `/^the following ((
```

How to auto populate for array values for file_names test1.pdf,test2.pdf??

Comment: Have you tried actually making it an array? [test1.pdf, test2.pdf]?

Comment: John very good point.  I was looking for a solution in Cucumber when I should have been looking at the ActiveRecord.  I was able to figure this out by doing the following code snipped:
    before_validation :update_file_names

    def update_file_names
      if file_names_changed? and !file_names.is_a?(Array)
        self.file_names = self.file_names.split(',').collect(&:strip) 
      end
    end